# Javascript Bookmarklet works in Chrome and FF but not IE

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I have created a JS bookmarklet to find all checkboxes in the Document and then toggle the checked state if the checkbox name matches a Regular Expression. **On the target webpage, the user must first click on the "Show More" button to open/load the DIV containing the target checkboxes. This** is what is causing the problem. The bookmarklet works in all browsers as expected when the checkboxes are explicitly defined in the HTML.

Here is the bookmarklet:

```
javascript:a=document.getElementsByTagName("input");for(b=0;b<a.length;b++)if(a[b]&&a[b].type=='checkbox'&&(/^sys_id_[a-z0-9]+$/).test(a[b].name))a[b].checked=!a[b].checked;
```

This bookmarklet works in Chrome as expected.

In Internet Explorer 11.0.9600.18525, there is no change on the page and nothing is logged in the [F12] Console.

In Firefox, the Document.Body.InnerHTML changes to 
"[object HTMLCollection]".

How can I modify this bookmarklet to work in all browsers, keeping in mind the checkboxes are loaded after the page is loaded?

Thanks,

-Zach

Comment: So you tried the code in IE dev's console and no errors show up?

Comment: Hi @JSelser, I open IE's Console window (F12) and then click the bookmarklet. Nothing shows up in the IE console window.

Comment: But have you tried pasting the code (everything **after** the `javascript:`) in the IE console and hit enter?